# Pandas - Apply Style/Formatting Based on Column Name and Value of a Row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
{'Compared': {0: -0.090909090999999997,
  1: -0.130434783,
  2: -0.10714285699999999,
  3: -0.15966386599999999},
 'LastYR': {0: 5500.0, 1: 115.0, 2: 84.0, 3: 40520.523399999998},
 'METRIC': {0: 'Visits', 1: 'Units', 2: 'Orders', 3: 'Sales'},
 'Today': {0: 5000.0, 1: 100.0, 2: 75.0, 3: 34050.860000000001},
 'region_rollup': {0: 'America', 1: 'America', 2: 'America', 3: 'America'}}

)
df2.head()
```

How can I apply:

a) a % format to any entire column I would like

b) A currency $ format to any row where the METRIC value is 'Sales'

[image]

I have tried the df.style.format() function, which will let me subset columns and apply the % formatting, but I cannot determine what kind of function to write which would allow me to format a column, based on the value of another column (again, "if metric = sales then format today as currency", more or less).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For first condition, if percentage of only numbers may be following would work too:

```
df2['%'] = (df2['LastYR']/ df2['LastYR'].sum()) * 100
```

For second condition, may be you can use, for e.g. if `METRIC` is `Sales`then, divide some other column value, in below if `Sales` then dividing `Today` column by 100.0, else keeping same as `Today` column value:

```
df2['Currency'] = df2.apply(lambda row: (row['Today'] / 100.0 if row['METRIC'] == 'Sales' else row['Today']), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
   Compared      LastYR  METRIC     Today region_rollup          %   Currency
0 -0.090909   5500.0000  Visits   5000.00       America  11.899733  5000.0000
1 -0.130435    115.0000   Units    100.00       America   0.248813   100.0000
2 -0.107143     84.0000  Orders     75.00       America   0.181741    75.0000
3 -0.159664  40520.5234   Sales  34050.86       America  87.669713   340.5086
```

## Update:

Using function and using `apply`:

```
def test_function(row):
    if row['METRIC'] == 'Sales':
        return row['Today'] / 100.0 
    else:
        return row['Today']
```

And using `lambda` and `apply` for each row:

`df2['Currency'] = df2.apply(lambda row: test_function(row), axis=1)`

## Update 2:

```
def test_function(row, column):
    if row['METRIC'] == 'Sales':
        return row[column] / 100.0 
    else:
        return row[column]

df2['%'] = (df2['LastYR']/ df2['LastYR'].sum()) * 100

column_list = ['Today', 'LastYR']
for column in column_list:
    df2[column] = df2.apply(lambda row: test_function(row, column), axis=1)
```

Comment: Close, but the else returns the column name, rather than the original value

Comment: Yes, sorry - I was mistaken and made an error while copying and pasting/trying  your solution. I believe this works. Any straightforward way to apply to a list of numerous columns? I'll accept as working.

Comment: Clarifying point: I have 10 comparison columns, which need currency formatting. Trying to get my head around performing that operation on each of them.

Comment: May be using function will help. Added the updates, to use function where may be defining multiple condition will be helpful.

Comment: Great, how to I handle this if I have 10 columns, or 9 if I already consider that "Today" is handled? Same logic for each of them

Comment: Do you want to change value in column itself or create new column as for e.g. in above new column `Currency` is created.

Comment: Ideally, keep the column name, just update the data in the column. Do not need to add more columns, just adjust the formatting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155214/discussion-between-0p3n5ource-and-jrjames83).